# AngularJS: Reference to controller dynamically (by name)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Working on a module based app where depending on the user, I'll load a given template (view) as a *module* inside a common view. The problem is that the different views require different controllers and they one share a small set of common form inputs.

Based on a call to my server I'll get a JSON response containing what view/controller should be loaded for that user. This solution worked fine earlier as all my controllers were in the global scope:

```
$scope.corporation.payloadController = 
          // Contains the String "ComputerPayloadCtrl"
          [window]data.corporation.payloadController;
```

Now however, after I have rewritten the applications to use the angular module design pattern, I get the following error (I no longer use [window]):

```
Argument 'corporation.payloadController' is not a function, got string
```

The controller is already defined, so I'm only looking for a way to reference it by String.

```
.controller('ComputerPayloadCtrl', ['PayloadService', '$scope',
    function(PayloadService, $scope) {
        $scope.payload = PayloadService.payload;
}])
```

The more I work with this problem, the more this entire approach I've chosen is bugging me. So if anyone has any suggestions on how to alternatively solve this I'll gladly hear it.

**Edit:** So I found a very simple workaround, but I'll let the question stand in case there is an actual way to do this.

Comment: Interested to see your workaround though :)

Comment: could you use `$injector` directly?

Comment: @Halcyon21 The workaround was done server side, so not that relevant to Angular I'm afraid.

Comment: @DavinTryon Didn't have any luck with that. Could be I used the wrong implementation though.